# Double tap using KIF

Tags: ios, mapbox, kif-framework, kif

How does one perform a double tap using KIF?

I've tried calling `tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:` twice and also add a delay between the two calls, but nothing works. The test don't fail meaning KIF is able to perform the individual taps but I don't know how to get a double tap.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[tester tapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(160.0, 284.0)];
[tester waitForTimeInterval:0.1];
[tester tapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(160.0, 284.0)];
[tester waitForTimeInterval:5.0];
```

The important parts are a short wait on the tester between taps and then a long wait on the tester after the taps in order for the gesture to be recognized and processed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify the point at screen, you may use this approach

```
// Code sample in Swift 5.3
// access the view instance by identifier or label
let view = tester().waitForView(withAccessibilityIdentifier: "view-accessibility-identifier") 
view?.tap() // taps at center of the view
tester().wait(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
view?.tap()
tester().wait(forTimeInterval: 2)
```